# Find interval containing given time instant

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, intervals

I am trying to solve the following problem: given N time intervals, each specified as (start, end), non-overlapping, sorted based on start - find an interval that contains a given date. For instance given:

```
[1,4] [5,8] [9,10][11,20]
```

3 falls into the first interval, 15 into fourth etc.

So far I had the following base ideas:

1. We can use binary seach to find the corresponding interval (Log N)
2. Since it might be the case that only a few intervals are big, and the rest small, it might be worthwhile sorting the itervals based on their duration. Then, statistically, most of the time we would 'hit' the longest intervals (O(1)), only sometimes this would result in the worst case complexity of N.

I was thinking whether there is a scope to combine the two approaches. One other idea is to sort based on the duration and insert all the intervals into a tree, with comparison by start date, This, in the worst case when longest durations are in chronological order, this approach is equal in performance to 2.

The ideal solution I imagined would be to have a tree (or some similar data structure) that would contain the longest interval on the top, then the two branches would have the next two longest intervals etc. However, I see no way to branch in that tree i.e. since we make an explicit assumption that we insert based on the length, we cannot really discard left or right side of the tree.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would stick to the first approach.

Comment: Look into splay trees if you think your distribution is correct.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make a BST sorted by key and prioritised by length. Beware, though, of degenerate trees.

Comment: so the combined approach I descriibed

Comment: I was thinking of this approach: Start with this tree and AVL-ify it

Comment: Are the ranges all adjacent (no missing bits)?  If that's the case, why can't you just consider the first number of each range only and look for the inflection point?

Comment: I could potentially, but then I would be reduced to simple array of values, and no "length" information is present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A naive combination of the two approaches offer a `O(1)` in most cases, and `O(logN)` worst case, but the hidden constant in the big O notation will be double:

1. Let the original array be `intervals`
2. Create a second array, as suggested sorted by lengths of intervals descending. Let it be `lengths`
3. For each query, search in both `intervals` using binary search, and in `lengths` using linear search. The search will be done in parallel<sup>1</sup>, and the first that finishes up - will cause the other one to stop as well.

Because in step 3, we may do up to `c*log(n)` steps of binary search in `intervals`, we will do up to `2*c*log(n)` steps overall. If we find the element faster in `lengths`, it will cause the binary search to end in the middle, and we will get the reduced number of operations, (but with a double constant then the original approach).

---

(1) No parallel computer is needed, it can be achieved by searching one step in each, simulating parallel computing on a single thread, until an answer is found. (General information, not needed for understanding the answer: The concept of "searching in parallel" was introduced by S.Even, A.Itai and A.Shamir in their article [On the Complexity of TimeTable and Multi Commodity Flow Problems](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~itai/publications/Algorithms/multi-commodity-timetables.pdf))

Comment: Nice approach; +1 but I think my answer deserves attention as well

Comment: how do you "stop" both approaches running in parallel? You just call Thread.interrupt?

Comment: @Bober02 no. you emulate multi-threading by alternating steps from both searches manually.

Answer (score 3):

You could prioritise certain nodes in binary search tree and still have it balanced:

Start with your combined approach (place longer intervals closer to the top) and employ a series of rotations to make the binary search tree balanced (while breaking *some* prioritisation, it should preserve high-priority nodes close to the root if they don't break the balance).

To balance a tree, try this strategy (untested):

- Balance the left half (subtree of the root)
- Balance the right half
- If the right half is higher than the left half by more than 1 (AVL balance condition

  - While this is true

    - If the right-left quarter (left half of right half) is higher than the right-right quarter, rotate the right subtree to the right (start an AVL double rotation)
    - Rotate the tree to the left (complete an AVL rotation)
    - Balance the left half (both left quarters are already balanced - start with #3)
- Else if the left half is higher than the right half by more than 1

  - do the converse of the other case

This should produce an AVL-balanced tree that respects the original priorities where possible.

Comment: Hmmm, this is interesting, but the ideas of splay trees might also be tempting: In most cases, if i prioritise a certain interval up the tree, I would get many subsequent dates falling into this interval. So splay tree rotation would be amortized, and on average itshould be O(1)

Comment: @Bober02 In prioritised AVL trees, you only rotate when compiling the tree, search is logarithmic guaranteed (unless I failed at making it balanced) and longer intervals are likely to be found sooner than shorter intervals. In splay trees you rotate after each search. Also I have bad experience in observing how well they're balanced (no word about their prioritisation capabilities - they seem to be good at keeping fresh nodes close to the top).

Comment: @Bober02 IMO splay trees are kinda ADHD'd :-)

Comment: @Bober02 You mean, you prefer solutions where reads are structural changes and need to be synchronised? :-)

Comment: It is a very nice approach, however I usually dislike trees for constant data due to poor caching. Can it somehow be implemented as an array (similar to how we implement a binary heap)? (+1 anyway for the nice approach)

Comment: @amit You could build a tree on top of an ordinary list (by storing indexes instead of memory pointers). This way, you have full control over allocation and thus caching. Note that a language that can reorder elements on the heap will likely outperform you in terms of memory organisation of tree nodes.

Comment: @amit You can use implicit indexes but tree rotations will end up costly - or you can use explicit indexes during compilation and then copy out to an array with implicit indexes (preventing (efficient) further modification but enabling more compact representation). Note that I don't consider an array-heap (with `2n+1; 2n+2` indexes) cache-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's may possible combing two together. Here's my thought,

Build a binary tree based on the length of range, suppose we have following range,

a: [0, 1), b: [1, 2), c: [3, 10), d: [11, 12), e: [13, 14)

We build the tree from bottom, we combine leafs based on the range size, so the first round we can get the internal leaf,

(a, b), c, (d, e)

then,

(a, b, c), (d, e)

the root will be,

(a, b, c, d, e)

In each round, we combine nodes with least range length, keep in mide the depth of the tree.

Each node points to left, right child and keep the min, max value of child nodes.

If anything wrong, please point out..

Comment: this is wrong - the intervals cannot be combined, otherwise there would be no problem at all, I wouls simply find the start of the first interval and end of the last and build new interval (start,end). No treee would be necessary

Comment: It's not really combine them, a node just indicate the leaf's min, max value, you need to go through the tree to leafs to find the required interval

Comment: It's just a search tree, when new input comes, search which interval it may be, either in left or right sub-tree.

Comment: So what do you gain by combining what informaton the left and right subtree contains? what if the left subtree has the intervals (1,2) (200, 390)? How would you combine this then? And what if the right subtree is (2,10) and (1000, 1001)?

Comment: This wouldn't happen, fist need to sort the original nodes, which i forgot to mention.

Comment: The tree will look like ((((1, 2), (5, 6)), (100, 102)), (1000, 2000). The advantage is that the large range is more close to the root, which means it can be find faster.

Comment: never mind, I absolutely don't get your answer, and besides i don't think it would bring anything on top simply sorting by the length and inserting into a TreeSet. You can try to rephrase your answer witha concrete, complex example, showing what the complexity is (if you feel like doing so)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

Using the first and last interval's data (average the duration and the times), estimate which interval statistically you would expect the time to be in. If that interval does not contain the target, re-perform the estimation with the estimated interval as one the array ends (the other end will be the closest actual end).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and TimeSlots (that is nearly equivalent to Joda Period).
Period was my custom class having start and end of type DateTime.
I held a TreeSet of Periods sorted by end date.

TimeSlot class:

```
public class TimeSlot<T> {
    private DateTime start;
    private DateTime end;

    // accessors
    ...
}
```

utility methods:

```
public TimeSlot<T> getTimeSlot(DateTime pointInTime) {
    for (TimeSlot<T> ts : getCounterTimeSlotSet()) {
        if (ts.getPeriod().isDateInRange(pointInTime)) {
            return ts;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public boolean isDateInRange(DateTime date) {
    if (date == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return date.isAfter(this.start.minusMillis(1)) 
        && date.isBefore(this.end.plusMillis(1));
}
```

Recently I found the [library](http://code.google.com/p/allenintervalrelationships/) that implements [Allen's Interval algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allen%27s_interval_algebra#Relations), you might find it useful.

Comment: it is indeed but it is really simple and intuitive(IMO).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably right that binary search wouldn't be optimum, with the odd distribution. Although, log_2(N) for N = 1 billion is only about 30.

A binary search of elements is optimal if each element in the list to be searched is equally likely.

Thus a multi-level binary search might be ideal here, where the intervals in each level are approximately the same size. Using the example given:

```
First Level: [1-10] [11-20] # Size = 10
Second Level: [1-10] = [1,4] [5,8] [9,10] # Size = 4
```

If between 11 and 20, then done, else expand [1-10] and check the intervals [1,4] [5,8] [9,10].

There's some extra cost in setting up the search structure thinking upwards of O(N log(N)) and is more costly for the small intervals, but it should have a rather good average search time if there is a big enough gap between largest and smallest interval size.

In the worst case, you'll have log(N) levels.